# MS Excel: save spreadsheet to tab-separated with UNIX end of lines and UTF-8?

Tags: microsoft-excel, utf-8

I have a tab-separated text file with a table that has UNIX end-of-line characters (i.e. `\n`) and UTF-8 encoding. I can open it in MS Excel 2010 without major problems using Data → Import and selecting related options. However, if I save it back into a text file using File → Save as → Tab-separated, I end up with a file with DOS end-of-lines (i.e. `\r\n`) and one-byte national Windows encoding (i.e. "ANSI").

Of course, I can restore proper end-of-lines and encoding with an external tool, but that looks like a lot of hassle in the long term.

Is there a quick way to save tab-separated file with UNIX EOLs and in UTF8 (i.e. using all the settings that were used during the import) in MS Excel?

Comment: are you open to using a VBA solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. Excel can't do that without using VBA.

**About different encodings**
Check [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences) about the different encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, Unicode, etc.)

**What Excel can do**
Microsoft Excel **can** export text files using ANSI ([Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which are [quite similar](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html)) or using [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (which is the same as UTF-16). Both have a DOS-style end-of-line ([CR]+[LF] or '\r\n' or in ASCII HEX code: 0x0D0A).

**What Excel can't do**
Microsoft Excel **can't** export UTF-8 and can't use UNIX style newlines ([LF] or '\n' or in ASCII HEX code: 0x0D).

See [this Microsoft Knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2585454) where this is confirmed. They revert to another tool (such as Notepad) to save the ANSI file to UTF-8.

For a VBA answer, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba).

Comment: Really? I was quite sure it supported at least UTF-16...

Comment: Excel actually has a Save As option for Unicode Text (*.txt).  However this is not UTF-8 and produces DOS end-of-line characters. You probably need to use an external tool e.g. Notepad++ and look into the Macro functionality.

Comment: @MikeHoney good point. Expanded the answer: mentioned ANSI as well as UTF-16 (Unicode) support and made a remark about CR+LF vs. LF too.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. A negative answer is still an answer.